# svcutil.exe cannot handle imports?

Tags: wcf, command-line, xsd, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I'm on a project in which a .NET frontend communicates with a Java backend. We use wdsl's + xsd's to describe the interface between front and backend. I'm on the frontend side in .NET 4.0. We used to generate code for the interfaces with xsd.exe & wsdl.exe, but we want to switch to WCF now, so I'm trying to use svcutil.exe. However, I keep getting errors. I've tracked it down to an `<import>` statement used, so I've  tried the example for that from the w3 site: 
[W3.org site import example](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_style)

I've saved those 3 example files there as StockQuoteService.wsdl, StockQuote.wsdl and StockQuote.xsd and set the location attribute to those files. I've fixed a bug (in StockQuoteService.wdsl the binding should be StockQuoteSoapBinding, not StockQuoteBinding). Then I run svcutil like this:

svcutil StockQuoteService.wsdl *.xsd /serializer:XmlSerializer

And presto, exactly the same errors as with our xsd/wsdl's:

> Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
>   Detail: Cannot find definition for http://example.com/stockquote/definitions:StockQuotePortType.  Service Description with namespace http://example.com/stockquote/definitions is missing.
>   Parameter name: name
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/stockquote/service']/wsdl:binding[@name='StockQuoteSoapBinding']

StockQuotePortType is in StockQuote.wsdl which is included in StockQuoteService.wsdl, but it seems like scvutil cannot find it. With our own files we have a similar situation.

I am new to WCF, can anyone explain what is going on here?